# collection.update({_id: 'an Object Id'}, {change}, {upsert:true}) should create the document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm using a call like the one at the title, because of the `upsert: true` it's supposed a document with that data should be created if it does not exists with that query data, but it's not being created. The call is

```
collection.update({_id: 'an Object Id'}, {$push: {data: data_var}}, {upsert: true}, callback);
```

The callback does not shows any error going from the first argument.

This should create the document? Or should I make a `find` first or what?

Comment: Yes, that will create create a document if one with a matching `_id` doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. There was an issue in my script doing this.